# Unity3D iBeacon Android Application has stopped

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, estimote

I have just started using Unity3D and my school project consists of using iBeacons and detecting them with my mobile device. I'm doing a 2D project and in my scene, I have an empty game object that contains code handling the detection of the iBeacon:

```
public class iBeaconReceiverExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector2 scrolldistance;
    private List<Beacon> mybeacons = new List<Beacon>();
    private bool scanning = true;
    private bool guion = false;
    public GameObject Nipper;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        iBeaconReceiver.BeaconRangeChangedEvent += OnBeaconRangeChanged;
        iBeaconReceiver.BluetoothStateChangedEvent += OnBluetoothStateChanged;
        iBeaconReceiver.CheckBluetoothLEStatus();
        Debug.Log("Listening for beacons");
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        iBeaconReceiver.BeaconRangeChangedEvent -= OnBeaconRangeChanged;
        iBeaconReceiver.BluetoothStateChangedEvent -= OnBluetoothStateChanged;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        foreach (Beacon b in mybeacons)
        {
            if (0.00 < b.accuracy && b.accuracy < 2.00)
            {
                CreateNipper();
            }
        }

    }

    public void CreateNipper()
    {
        GameObject nipper = Instantiate(Nipper, new Vector3(1, 1, -7), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        nipper.transform.SetParent(transform);
    }

    private void OnBluetoothStateChanged(BluetoothLowEnergyState newstate)
    {
        switch (newstate)
        {
            case BluetoothLowEnergyState.POWERED_ON:
                iBeaconReceiver.Init();
                Debug.Log("It is on, go searching");
                break;
            case BluetoothLowEnergyState.POWERED_OFF:
                //iBeaconReceiver.EnableBluetooth();
                Debug.Log("It is off, switch it on");
                break;
            case BluetoothLowEnergyState.UNAUTHORIZED:
                Debug.Log("User doesn't want this app to use Bluetooth, too bad");
                break;
            case BluetoothLowEnergyState.UNSUPPORTED:
                Debug.Log("This device doesn't support Bluetooth Low Energy, we should inform the user");
                break;
            case BluetoothLowEnergyState.UNKNOWN:
            case BluetoothLowEnergyState.RESETTING:
            default:
                Debug.Log("Nothing to do at the moment");
                break;
        }
    }

    private void OnBeaconRangeChanged(List<Beacon> beacons)
    {
        // 
        foreach (Beacon b in beacons)
        {
            if (mybeacons.Contains(b))
            {
                mybeacons[mybeacons.IndexOf(b)] = b;
            }
            else
            {
                // this beacon was not in the list before
                // this would be the place where the BeaconArrivedEvent would have been spawned in the the earlier versions
                mybeacons.Add(b);
            }
        }
        foreach (Beacon b in mybeacons)
        {
            if (b.lastSeen.AddSeconds(10) < DateTime.Now)
            {
                // we delete the beacon if it was last seen more than 10 seconds ago
                // this would be the place where the BeaconOutOfRangeEvent would have been spawned in the earlier versions
                mybeacons.Remove(b);
            }
        }
    }
```

The "Init()" method starts the iBeacon plugin and starts searching for an iBeacon around my mobile device. My only concern here is that I have two scenes and once I go to another scene (a random scene) and go back to the original scene (the one containing the iBeaconReceiverExample script), my application crashes "Unfortunately, (Game Name) has stopped."

I have used adb Logcat to track the log of my device but it hasn't helped me at all. I have tried making two whole new scenes (thinking that maybe my scene was going crazy) but nothing worked. When I don't attach this script to my game object, my application doesn't crash so clearly the problem has to be somewhere here.

Have someone played with iBeacons on Unity and encountered this problem? What is the solution to this problem?

Thank you in advance! :)